# Not creating txt file in c drive by file operations in C language

Tags: c, file-management, turbo-c++

I am trying to create a simple text file using **TurboC++ DOS emulator**. But, it's not creating the file. I am referring to an online video where the same file is getting created. What can be the issue?

Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int num;
  FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("c:\\program.txt","w");

  if(fptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("error");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("enter num = ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  fprintf(fptr,"%d",num);
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the C: drive? Run your application with elevated privileges.

Comment: suggestion and possible problem: remove `null` from your code; use predefined `NULL` instead.

Comment: "it's not creating the file", but is it showing the "error" for failed opening? Do you run the program in an environment where you reliably see the output? I.e. the program might temporarily open a window, print "error" and then close it again. Run your program from a commandline which afterwards remains open. You do run it like "myprogram.exe", don't you? (I ask because sometimes people confuse "running" and "compiling/building".)

Comment: Just for fun and good luck, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, this answer may no longer be required, I am providing it here for future reference of those who might need it.

I had the same problem some time ago.

It turns out the DOS emulator emulates the PC storage for programs.
The folder *C:\TurboC++\Disk* is treated as *C:\* by TurboC++, and it is the root folder for whatever TurboC++ needs to refer to.

[image: TurboC++ Root]

So, your file program.txt, should have the path *[Your Installation Path]:\TurboC++\Disk* when seen from outside TurboC++.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the prompt in the DOS emulator and do something like `DIR > C:\program.txt`, check if you get an error and if not then check with `DIR C:\` if that file is actually created.

If that doesn't work it's not a problem with your C application, but with the possibility to write there (like file access rights or a read-only drive).

Answer (score 0):

I switched DOS emulator to code blocks.